Error while loading shared libraries when running C application with subprocess.run
keyfinder-cli: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyfinder.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I cannot run
def get_key(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["keyfinder-cli", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    return str(result.stdout)

a CLI application from python that depends on libkeyfinder. ldconfig loads the objects correctly
ubuntu@vps-xxx:~/$ docker compose exec -it ... sh
# ldconfig -p | grep keyfinder
    libkeyfinder.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libkeyfinder.so.2
    libkeyfinder.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libkeyfinder.so

I even set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run ldconfig just to be sure before building keyfinder-cli
RUN git clone https://github.com/evanpurkhiser/keyfinder-cli.git
WORKDIR /keyfinder-cli

RUN apt -y install libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswresample-dev
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
RUN ldconfig &&\
    make &&\
    make install

what is wrong here?
I also tried to
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib", "keyfinder-cli", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running, no avail. In Docker I do the basically same thing ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib. exporting will do nothing.
edit: see answer

Okay, never mind, this is not related with C at all.
def get_key(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["keyfinder-cli", filename],
        env=dict(os.environ), # see this
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    return str(result.stdout)

in python subprocess.run, environment variables of the host OS is not inherited, and due to that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is always empty and does not exist.
